# In primeng how can we get the default dropdown value filter for a column of a table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

[image][image]   `enter code here`    <p-dropdown [options]="statuses" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, 'status', 'equals')" `enter code here`   styleClass="p-column-filter" placeholder="Select a Status" `enter code here`[showClear]="true">`enter code here`
  `enter code here`
<span [class]="'customer-badge status-' + option.value"> `enter code here`
{{option.label}}  `enter code here`
`enter code here`
`enter code here`

I'm reffering to this document https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/filter, here for the status column how can we make it a default selected value and that default value related rows should only display

Comment: Does anyone knows, how to do it ?

Comment: You are reading wrong documentation, you should use the https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown as reference.

Comment: The link which i shared is correct, i'm checking for a default option of a dropdown of a column, For suppose the Status NEW should be default selected and the New status related rows should appear.

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation for `p-dropdown`. Maybe play a little bit in the playground on stackblitz and then try again.

Comment: But what is your problem or what do you want to achieve? I didn't understand you very well. Do you want to get the selected value in the dropdown?

Comment: @Alba, I need the view like the table 1 which i had attached, the default value is Qualified from the dropdown so the Status column should have the Qualified related data.

Comment: Maybe this example can help you: https://embed.plnkr.co/ozZJ21SeNFVA16ng4NRl/ . But if you don't put your whole code, I don't know if I can help you